# Append to a numpy array without loading the entire array into RAM

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to append to a numpy array without loading it into RAM? I am trying to create a large numpy array that is bigger than my RAM on google colab, and then using memmap to read parts of it at a time. I have the second part figured out but I have no way of creating hte large numpy array in the first place.

Comment: Use `numpy.memmap`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html

Comment: How? Is there an example you could point me to?

Comment: The docs I linked have an example of how to create a `numpy.memmap` array.  They work pretty much like a normal `numpy.ndarray`.  You need to be more specific.